# Locale-related code -- are there corner cases I didn't see?

Tags: java, parsing, i18n

This is a utility class I have in one of my projects and I seek feedback on it. I have read the [javadoc for `Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) quite a few times while developing this code.  I think I have it right, but maybe there are holes in it...

Reviews welcome; also, if there are parts of the code you don't understand due to lack of comments, I'd like to hear about that as well.

Link to the original source: [here](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/msgsimple/locale/LocaleUtils.java); test file for this class: [here (not pasted in this post)](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/fge/msgsimple/locale/LocaleUtilsTest.java).

Note: this library is meant to work with Java 6+; I know of the `Locale.Builder` class, however this class only appeared in Java 7.

```
/**
 * Utility methods for {@link Locale} management
 *
 * <p>This class provides two methods:</p>
 *
 * <ul>
 *     <li>{@link #parseLocale(String)} parses a string and builds a {@link
 *     Locale} object (strangely enough, there is no such method in the JDK!);
 *     </li>
 *     <li>{@link #getApplicable(Locale)} returns an ordered list of locales
 *     "applicable" to the given locale.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p>The {@link #getApplicable(Locale)} method emulates what the JDK's {@link
 * ResourceBundle} does when you look up a message in a locale; it returns an
 * ordered list from the most specific to the more general. For instance, given
 * the locale {@code "ja_JP_JP"}, it will generate the following list:</p>
 *
 * <ul>
 *     <li>{@code "ja_JP_JP"},</li>
 *     <li>{@code "ja_JP"},</li>
 *     <li>{@code "ja"},</li>
 *     <li>{@code ""} (the root locale, {@link Locale#ROOT}).</li>
 * </ul>
 */
public final class LocaleUtils
{
    private static final Pattern UNDERSCORE = Pattern.compile("_");

    private LocaleUtils()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Parse a string input as an argument and return a locale object
     *
     * <p>Three things to note:</p>
     *
     * <ul>
     *     <li>it is NOT checked whether the extracted language or country codes
     *     are actually registered to the ISO;</li>
     *     <li>all input strings with more than two underscores are deemed
     *     illegal;</li>
     *     <li>if the first component (the language) is empty, {@link
     *     Locale#ROOT} is returned.</li>
     * </ul>
     *
     * @see Locale
     *
     * @param input the input string
     * @throws NullPointerException input is null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException input is malformed (see above)
     * @return a {@link Locale}
     */
    public static Locale parseLocale(final String input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("input cannot be null");

        if (input.isEmpty())
            return Locale.ROOT;

        /*
         * NOTE NOTE NOTE: in order for .split() to behave in a sane manner, we
         * MUST use the "multi-argument" version of .split() with a negative
         * argument. The no-argument version (this also stands for String's
         * .split()) will remove all empty strings from the end of the resulting
         * array up to the first non empty element.
         *
         * I don't know who designed this API, but he should either be given
         * the boot or killed[1].
         *
         * [1] choose the better option; hint: choose option 2
         */
        final String[] elements = UNDERSCORE.split(input, -1);
        final int len = elements.length;

        if (len > 3)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("malformed input " + input);
        if (elements[0].isEmpty())
            return Locale.ROOT;

        switch (len) {
            case 1:
                return new Locale(elements[0]);
            case 2:
                return new Locale(elements[0], elements[1]);
            case 3:
                return new Locale(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2]);
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("How did I get there??");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get a "decrementing" list of candidate locales for a given locale
     *
     * <p>The order of locale returned is from the more specific to the less
     * specific (the latter being {@link Locale#ROOT}).</p>
     *
     * @param target the locale
     * @return the list of applicable locales
     */
    public static Collection<Locale> getApplicable(final Locale target)
    {
        final String language = target.getLanguage();
        final String country = target.getCountry();
        final String variant = target.getVariant();

        final List<Locale> ret = new ArrayList<Locale>();
        ret.add(target);

        Locale locale;

        if (!variant.isEmpty()) {
            locale = new Locale(language, country);
            if (!locale.equals(Locale.ROOT))
                ret.add(locale);
        }

        if (!country.isEmpty()) {
            locale = new Locale(language);
            if (!locale.equals(Locale.ROOT))
                ret.add(locale);
        }

        if (!language.isEmpty())
            ret.add(Locale.ROOT);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's some neat code and good documentation, very nice job! The only thing I can see is your declaration of `len`, which you use only one time and happily not use it the next time, I'd suggest to drop that variable.

Comment: Uhm, yup, well spotted...

Comment: OK, the code has changed a little since then, to account for the comment above; and I think I have detected a bug... However, I am working on another part of this project at the moment :p

Comment: Actually, there was a bug with some inputs. But the bug is in `.split()`...

Comment: in parseLocale, checking for null is useless, the exception will happen when you do input.isEmpty()

Comment: @grasGendarme yup, but the exception message in such a case is meaningless...

Answer (score 5):

In general, your code is well structured, and well documented.

As for the `-1` requirement for `split`, Java has done *the right thing* by keeping the behaviour consistent with the [Perl *RegEx library*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) .... so blame Perl (and perhaps Perl can blame someone else).

My more significant issue is that, based on the fact that you have written this utility class, I expect that you are calling these methods 'often'. Since Local instances can be slow to create from scratch, I imagine that you have a performance problem too. Creating many `Locale` instances is not a great idea when they are thread-safe, and can be reused easily between threads/invocations.

My recommendation to you would be to use a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` to store the `Locale`s you create, and to do a lookup from the Map first, and only create the `Locale` if you need to.

Something like:

```
// rename parseLocale(String input) and make it private.....
private static final internalParseLocale(String ...) {
}

private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Locale> localemap = new ConcurrentHashMap<> ();

// new public method
public static final Locale parseLocale(final String input) {
    final Locale gotit = localemap.get(input);
    if (gotit != null) {
        return gotit;
    }
    final Locale created = internalParseLocale(input);
    final Locale wasthere = localemap.putIfAbsent(input, created);
    if (wasthere != null) {
        // there was a race condition, and we lost!
        return wasthere;
    }
    return created;
}
```

Then, in your `getApplicable()` method you should:

- avoid using `new Locale(...)` but instead use `parseLocale(.....)`
- reuse the locales there too

Comment: Well, it is not called that often, but thanks for the tips!